# asp.net webservice function showing publicly

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

When I access the web service through the URL it shows me all the available functions. I want to restrict showing all the available functions publicly in the web service.

In other terms, I want the functions to be available with the web service but not to be shown to a user.
What settings/code are needed to accomplish this?

here is my web.config code

Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->

```
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.htm"/>
    <!-- 
        Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
        symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
        affects performance, set this value to true only 
        during development.
    -->
    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/><add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/><add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/><add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/></assemblies></compilation>
    <!--
        The <authentication> section enables configuration 
        of the security authentication mode used by 
        ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
<webServices>
   <protocols>
    <remove name="Documentation"/>
    <!--<remove name="HttpSoap"/>-->
    <!--<remove name="HttpSoap12"/>-->        
  </protocols>
</webServices>
    <sessionState timeout="01" mode="InProc"></sessionState>
<authentication mode="Windows">     
</authentication>

    <!--The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
        of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
        during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
        it enables developers to configure html error pages 
        to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
    </customErrors>-->
    <pages validateRequest="true" viewStateEncryptionMode="Always">
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></controls></pages>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/><add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/></httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></httpModules></system.web>
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider,System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/></compiler>
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
            <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/></compiler></compilers></system.codedom>
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
        <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
        <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/><add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/></handlers></system.webServer>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/></dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding></runtime></configuration>
```

Comment: Is this ASMX, WCF SOAP, WCF Rest, ASP.NET Web API or some other system?

Comment: yes it is an ASMX system.

Answer (score 1):

If this is WCF, disable service metadata, do this in your web.config file:

(from [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751498(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751498%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) )

To disable WCF WSDL:

```
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="yourServiceBehavior">
            <!--
            The serviceMetadata behavior publishes metadata through 
            the IMetadataExchange contract. When this behavior is 
            present, you can expose this contract through an endpoint 
            as shown below. Setting httpGetEnabled to true publishes 
            the service's WSDL at the <baseaddress>?wsdl, for example,
            http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc?wsdl
            -->
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

To disable WCF MEX, remove or comment-out the `binding="mexHttpBinding"` `<endpoint>` element, which will look like this:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

(Note that also specifying `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false">` will also disable mex, but the MEX endpoint will still exist)

If this is ASMX, put this in your configuration:

```
<system.web>    
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <remove name="Documentation"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
</system.web>
```

Documentation pages for ASP.NET Web API are handled differently, refer to this article for an explanation: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages

Comment: I HAVE USED THE ASMX CONFIGURATION BUT WHEN I TEST THE WEB SERVICE IT SHOWS AN ERROR SAYING **Request format is unrecognized.**

Comment: @user2408256 Please post your entire web.config file into your original question.